# Is there a way to trick my android phone and change the SSID name that it's currently connected to?

Tags: wi-fi

My android phone is connected to a device broadcasting the SSID: 12345A
Is there a way to trick my phone into thinking the currently connected SSID is 12345B?
I'm trying to connect to a stupid chinese device which has a slightly different SSID than its app expects.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to change it in settings at device A

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define a new network, by going to settings then wifi & Add network then define the other SSID.